# How can I change the UINavigationBar's background image via Interface Builder in XCode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, uinavigationbar

How can I change the `UINavigationBar`'s background image for all view controllers which works with this `UINavigationController` via Interface Builder in XCode 6? unfortunately, changing "Back Image" option's value doesn't change the background image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
add this line inside  app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: @adnan Can I change it via Interface Builder?

Comment: interface builder has only back image option . that never works for you. Actually we have to set titleview image of navigationbar . I am not sure if we can change it in interface builder. This line will work fine

Comment: @adnan Will it set the background image for all navigation controller's bars in application?

Comment: yes it will set for all

Comment: @adnan Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The whole code is `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        
        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "navigation_bar.png")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        
        return true
    }`

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is the wrong image, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {

          UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg"];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


            return YES;
        }
```